# Write/Read/Delete binary data in Spark Databricks (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, binary, databricks

I'm quite new to Spark on Databricks (Scala) and I would like to know how I can write a variable's content which is of type `Array[Byte]` to a temporary file `data.bin` in a mount storage `mtn/somewhere/tmp/` (Azure Data Lake) or to `file:/tmp/`. Then I would like to know how to read it as an InputStream and later delete it when I'm done with it.

All methods I've read so far does not work or does not apply to binary data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this code works fine :

```scala
import java.io._
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

// Create or collect the data
val bytes: Array[Byte] = <some_data>

try {
    // Write data to temp file
    // Note : Here I use GRIB2 file as I manipulate forecast data,
    //        but you can use .bin or .png/.jpg (if it's an image data)
    //        extensions or no extension at all. It doesn't matter.
    val path: String = "mf-data.grib"
    val file: File = new File(path)
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, bytes)
    
    // Read the temp file
    val input = new FileInputStream(path)

        ////////// Do something with it //////////

    // Remove the temp file
    if (!file.delete()) {
        println("Cannot delete temporary file !")
    }
} catch {
    case _: Throwable => println("An I/O error occured")
```